# how to make these two sentances into one

Tags: grammar

1. "He told me he would come back in 1 hour."
2. "He lied to me."

I am a English beginner, please teach me how to combine these two sentences, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

When joining two propositions into one sentence, you can add a logical link between the two, usually in the form of a preposition.

The most simple logical links are "and", "but" and "then".

- "and" is very neutral;
- "but" expresses an opposition;
- "then" expresses either the passing of time, or a logical consequence.

In this case, there is an opposition between what he told you and the truth, so I would prefer "but".

> He told me that he would come back in 1 hour, but he lied to me.

You can also build a more complex link to give more information:

> He told me that he would come back in 1 hour, but after waiting for him the whole day, I have to face the conclusion that he lied to me.

Comment: thank you very much for the clear answer.